# Android does service stopSelf() still require return

Tags: android, android-service

Is it necessary to call return; if I have decided to call stopSelf() command in a onStartCommand() within a service?

Comment: Who said you must add a return statement? If you are inside onStartCommand() method, you have to return an integer

Comment: I've clarified my question.

Comment: If a function has a return type, it must return a value.  Calling stopSelf doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The method must have a `return` statement because the signature for `onStartCommand()` indicates that it returns a value:

```
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, 
            int flags, 
            int startId)
```